# why pixi.js set field to null when destroy?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have study pixi.js these day,and I noticed the destoy function was appear several in the source code,It looks like this.

```
/**
 * Removes everything from the renderer and optionally removes the Canvas DOM element.
 *
 * @param {boolean} [removeView=false] - Removes the Canvas element from the DOM.
 */
destroy(removeView)
{
    this.destroyPlugins();

    // call the base destroy
    super.destroy(removeView);

    this.context = null;

    this.refresh = true;

    this.maskManager.destroy();
    this.maskManager = null;

    this.smoothProperty = null;
}
```

Why it need set field to null?In my opinion when the host Object be garbage collected,all the field will be auto garbage collected,so manually set field to null looks like useless.

Because it was a famous framework,I think it may has some reason,can anyone tell me?

Comment: But garbage collection means, that there are no references to an object and the memory it uses, is automatically released for others to use. But using destroy function doesn't mean the object gets garbage collected, the object might still linger around and be used, even if it's destroyed. I have never really got around this part of pixi, so it's just a theory of what might be the use for it. So even after destroying an object, it doesn't necessarily get garbage collected and you can't really force the garbage collection from destroy.

Comment: Yes,you're right.But that's not what I mean.For example,when i use pixi.js and i want to release a sprite,I will call destory first and set that sprite reference to null.When i call destory i just want to ensure no elsewhere to reference this object,such as destory function of displayObject,"  this.parent.removeChild(this);" this was truely useful,but other line such as set field to null i think was useless.Because i get no answer first so i send a issue at https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/issues/4302.